# How do I insert the missing rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a table like this:

| FK_ID | Name | Updated_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLANNED | [Some Date] |
| 1 | DOING | [Some Date] |
| 2 | PLANNED | [Some Date] |
| 2 | DOING | [Some Date] |
| 2 | DONE | [Some Date] |
| 3 | PLANNED | [Some Date] |

The problem I'm having is I'd like to insert all missing PLANNED, DOING, DONE for every set of FK_ID's into the table so the result would be

| FK_ID | Name | Updated_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLANNED | [Some Date] |
| 1 | DOING | [Some Date] |
| 1 | DONE | [Blank] |
| 2 | PLANNED | [Some Date] |
| 2 | DOING | [Some Date] |
| 2 | DONE | [Some Date] |
| 3 | PLANNED | [Some Date] |
| 3 | DOING | [Blank] |
| 3 | DONE | [Blank] |

I had the idea to create a table, although I'm sure a temp table would be fine that would just be

| Name |
| --- |
| PLANNED |
| DOING |
| DONE |

and then do something with OUTER LEFT JOIN and/or NOT IN's but I'm not getting what I'm looking for. I'm thinking I need to have a query with a subquery with those but SQL guy I am not. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM ActualData e
OUTER LEFT JOIN TempTable i
ON e.Name = i.Name WHERE i.Name IS NULL
```

This does give me some data, but only the ones that don't appear in ANY of the records of the ActualData table.

Comment: It's `left outer join`, not `outer left join`. (Or better still, since `inner` and `outer` keywords are redundant, `left join`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to use a cross join to get all the combinations, and then remove those that already exist:

```sql
SELECT fk_id, t.name
FROM   ActualData
CROSS JOIN temp_table t
MINUS
SELECT fk_id, name
FROM   ActualData
```

Of course, this query can be used to insert the "missing" rows back into `ActualData`:

```sql
INSERT INTO ActualData (fk_id, name)
SELECT fk_id, t.name
FROM   ActualData
CROSS JOIN temp_table t
MINUS
SELECT fk_id, name
FROM   ActualData
```

Comment: Did not know about the MINUS keyword. I'll give this a go and report back!

Comment: Very cool, worked like a charm. Wasn't sure if this was solvable, my hat is off to you stranger :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [partitioned join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#DWHSG02013) with static list on status column to generate rows with missing statuses for each partition column (`fk_id`).

> ```
> with test_tab(FK_ID, Name, Updated_Date) as (
> select 1, 'PLANNED', '[Some Date]' from dual union all
> select 1, 'DOING', '[Some Date]' from dual union all
> select 2, 'PLANNED', '[Some Date]' from dual union all
> select 2, 'DOING', '[Some Date]' from dual union all
> select 2, 'DONE', '[Some Date]' from dual union all
> select 3, 'PLANNED', '[Some Date]' from dual
> )
> select
>   a.fk_id,
>   b.column_value as name,
>   a.updated_date
> from table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
>     'PLANNED',
>     'DOING',
>     'DONE'
>   )) b
>   left join test_tab a
>     partition by (fk_id)
>   on a.name = b.column_value
> ```
>
> ```
> FK_ID | NAME    | UPDATED_DATE
> ----: | :------ | :-----------
>     1 | DOING   | [Some Date] 
>     1 | DONE    | null        
>     1 | PLANNED | [Some Date] 
>     2 | DOING   | [Some Date] 
>     2 | DONE    | [Some Date] 
>     2 | PLANNED | [Some Date] 
>     3 | DOING   | null        
>     3 | DONE    | null        
>     3 | PLANNED | [Some Date]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ac052fcb899421cad7b67dd1d80977cb)*

Comment: The table above is sample data, the actual data is thousands of records. How would I get the first part without writing out sql statements for every row?

Comment: The first part is just a sample data, named subquery that may be reused as a plain table. An actual solution starts at line 9